# Write a paired sequence of strings based on two lists using jinja and python

Tags: python, list, jinja2

I have two lists of strings with the same length that I would like to pass to a template with jinja

```
acronym = ['A','B','C','D']
full_name = ['full_A','full_B','full_C','full_D']
```

I would like to link them in a legend of a figure such that the output should look like:

```
Fig.1: Bla.... 
A - full_A; B - full_B; C - full_C; and D - full_D.
```

I am writing on the template the following

```
@{@for (acronym in data.acronym) and (full in data.full_name)@}@
@{{@acronym@}}@ - @{{@full@}}@; @{@ endfor @}@}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: I would strongly suggest combining the acronyms and full names in one datatype, so you can keep them together. A list of tuples or a dictionary would make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be doing a for loop with range() function as follows:

```
@{@for i in range(0,data.acronym|length)@}@
@{{@data.acronym[i]@}}@-@{{@data.full[i]@}}@; 
@{@ endfor @}@
```

And to have the "and" word for the last enumeration do an if inside the for loop:

```
@{@for i in range(0,data.acronym|length)@}@
@{@if not loop.last@}@@{{@data.acronym[i]@}}@ - @{{@data.full[i]@}}@;
@{@ else @}@
and @{{@data.acronym[i]@}}@ - @{{@data.full[i]@}}@@{@endif@}@
@{@ endfor @}@
```

I am using @{@...@}@ to block functions and @{{@...@}}@ to block variables in jinja.

As Thom Wiggers suggested, another way is to define a different structure in python.